# Can't connect to neo4j via py2neo

Tags: python, flask, neo4j, py2neo

I'm using py2neo in wsl and trying to connect to neo4j instance on Windows.

```
from py2neo import Graph

graph = Graph('bolt://localhost:7687', user="neo4j", password="12345678")
```

the terminal returns with the error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/tranminhq420/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py2neo/client/**init**.py",
> line 806, in acquire
> cx = self._free_list.popleft() IndexError: pop from an empty deque
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/tranminhq420/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py2neo/wiring.py",
> line 62, in open
> s.connect(address) ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/tranminhq420/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py2neo/client/bolt.py",
> line 355, in open
> wire = cls._connect(profile, on_broken=on_broken)   File "/home/tranminhq420/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py2neo/client/bolt.py",
> line 369, in _connect
> wire = Wire.open(profile.address, keep_alive=True, on_broken=on_broken)   File
> "/home/tranminhq420/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py2neo/wiring.py",
> line 64, in open
> raise_from(WireError("Cannot connect to %r" % (address,)), error)   File "", line 3, in raise_from py2neo.wiring.WireError: Cannot
> connect to IPv4Address(('localhost', 7687))
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "graph.py", line 3, in
>
> graph = Graph('bolt://localhost:7687', user="neo4j", password="12345678")   File
> "/home/tranminhq420/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py2neo/database.py",
> line 288, in **init**
> self.service = GraphService(profile, **settings)   File "/home/tranminhq420/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py2neo/database.py",
> line 119, in **init**
> self._connector = Connector(profile, **connector_settings)   File "/home/tranminhq420/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py2neo/client/**init**.py",
> line 960, in **init**
> self._add_pools(*self._initial_routers)   File "/home/tranminhq420/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py2neo/client/**init**.py",
> line 982, in _add_pools
> pool = ConnectionPool.open(   File "/home/tranminhq420/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py2neo/client/**init**.py",
> line 649, in open
> seeds = [pool.acquire() for _ in range(init_size or cls.default_init_size)]   File
> "/home/tranminhq420/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py2neo/client/**init**.py",
> line 649, in 
> seeds = [pool.acquire() for _ in range(init_size or cls.default_init_size)]   File
> "/home/tranminhq420/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py2neo/client/**init**.py",
> line 813, in acquire
> cx = self._connect()   File "/home/tranminhq420/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py2neo/client/**init**.py",
> line 764, in _connect
> cx = Connection.open(self.profile, user_agent=self.user_agent,   File
> "/home/tranminhq420/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py2neo/client/**init**.py",
> line 174, in open
> return Bolt.open(profile, user_agent=user_agent,   File "/home/tranminhq420/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py2neo/client/bolt.py",
> line 364, in open
> raise_from(ConnectionUnavailable("Cannot open connection to %r" % profile), error)   File "", line 3, in raise_from
> py2neo.errors.ConnectionUnavailable: Cannot open connection to
> ConnectionProfile('bolt://localhost:7687')

I have suspected there's a problem with the conf of neo4j and have tried to uncomment the line

```
server.default_listen_address=0.0.0.0
```

to no avail. I have also tried to add the line

```
dbms.connector.bolt.address=0.0.0.0:7687
```

but still can't get it to connect, here's my [conf](https://anotepad.com/notes/bn8dg9dg) file, what should I do here

Comment: what is the neo4j version you are using?  Btw, py2neo support has ended. fyi. https://community.neo4j.com/t/farewell-py2neo-what-happens-now/64419

Comment: @jose_bacoy I'm currently using neo4j 5.12.0. That's unfortunate, is there any alternative you might suggest?

Comment: You should probably use the [official neo4j Python driver](https://neo4j.com/docs/python-manual/current/).